# Localization and quotient ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $X= V(F_1,\ldots, F_n)\subseteq\mathbb A^n_k$ an affine variety ($X$ is irreducible so the ideal $ I(X)=(F_1,\ldots, F_n)$ is prime).
For $x\in X$ consider the following two local rings:

1. $R:=\mathcal O_{\mathbb A^n_k,x}={k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]}_{\mathfrak m}$, 
   where $\mathfrak m=\{F\in k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\,:\, F(x)=0\}$.
2. $S:=\mathcal O_{X,x}= {\Gamma(X)}_{\mathfrak n}$, where $\Gamma(X)$ is the coordinate ring of $X$ and moreover $\mathfrak n=\{f\in \Gamma(X)\,:\, f(x)=0\}$

D.Arapura in his book at page 39 (first line) says that $S\cong R\big/I(X)$. Now clearly $\Gamma (X)=k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/I(X)$ and $\mathfrak n=\pi(\mathfrak m)$ under the projection to quotients so by the property of localization one should have that
$$S\cong R\bigg /{I(X)}_{\mathfrak m}$$

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think, it's a matter of notation. Once you wrote $R/I(X)$ it automatically means $I(X)$ is the corresponding ideal of $R$ after the localization. That's, $I(X)$ as an ideal of $R$ is what you wrote as $I(X)_m.$

Answer (score 1):

You are right. But as Kermani points out, it is simply a matter of notation. When Arapura writes $R/I(X)$, he really means $R/I(X)R$, and it is true that $I(X)R = I(X)_{\mathfrak m}$.

(However, be careful. The fact that $X = V(F_1, \dots, F_n)$ is irreducible does not imply that $\left<F_1, \dots, F_n\right>$ is a prime ideal, but that its *radical* is a prime ideal.)